# Font symbol for the TikZ Latex arrow (or something like it)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, symbols, arrows, tikz-arrows

Is there a package with a symbol for something like the Latex-style arrow in TikZ (an arrow with a solid/filled, slightly curved tip)? I know I can draw one using TikZ but I imagine there's a package that includes such a symbol. Something like this:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-Latex] (0,0) -- (0.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "\usetikzlibrary{arrows,math}" in your preambule, followed by "\draw[-Latex] ..." in your drawing.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS For the `Latex` arrow tip you need the `arrows.meta` library, not the (now deprecated) `arrows` library.

Comment: Please, could you reproduce the symbol with a drawing, so I understand your question? Thank you very much.

Comment: Search for *The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List*, there are listed bunch of symbols ...

Comment: Thanks. Before posting my question, I searched that list without success. So if the list is truly comprehensive, I guess the answer to my question is "no."

Comment: If it's still a problem: in which context do you want to use this arrow, e.g. drawing, text, math-mode?

Comment: I'd like to use it in math mode as a logical connective like \wedge or \vee.

Answer (score 2):

Without TikZ, pure [picture mode](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Picture) (to refine depending on the context you want to use it, as MS-SPO commented):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(10,10)
  \put(0,0){\vector(1,0){10}} 
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Taking CarLaTex' approach a step further, you can use the drawn arrow like ordinary text by `\newcommand\arw`. However, as you can see, some adjustments are needed for proper white spacing. My solutions certainly will fail with different fonts and can be refined by using proper Latex constants, but you get the idea.

Text:
[image: arrow in text]

Zoomed in:

[image: zoomed in]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newcommand\arw[0]{%
  \begin{picture}(13,10)% allow some space after the tip
    \put(0,0.3em){\vector(1,0){10}}% shift it up a little
  \end{picture}}


\begin{document}
Lorem \arw ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer rutrum Aenean vitae Phasellus risus. Vivamus et ridiculus Suspendisse Vestibulum hendrerit dolor ipsum congue.

Et ac quis pharetra convallis tempus pellentesque id Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada. Vitae et Maecenas Ut hendrerit quis \arw sagittis arcu mi vitae lobortis. At.

\arw

Tortor mus neque egestas habitant sed laoreet quis purus pede lacinia. Suscipit vel Vivamus laoreet dis Cras elit ipsum consequat eget orci. $a \arw b$ Massa diam.

$a \arw b$

\end{document}
```

Here's a version with CarLaTex' suggestion wrt `\mathrel` :

[image: mathrel]

Relevant code changes:

```
Tortor mus neque egestas habitant sed laoreet quis purus pede lacinia. Suscipit vel Vivamus laoreet dis Cras elit ipsum 
consequat eget orci. $a \arw b$ Massa $ab \mathrel{\arw} bc$ diam.

$a \arw b$

$ab \mathrel{\arw bc}$
```

Comment: +1, for math mode I'd use `\mathrel{\arw}`

Comment: The arrow in these solutions looks like it has the tail poking through the arrowhead. is there a solution that makes the point of the arrowhead the rightmost part of the symbol?

Comment: Sure, you can replace the contents of \arw{} with the Tikz-solution. "Poking" may be an artifact: that's how vectors look like in said solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, comparing the `picture` and the `\tikz` approach. As you can see, some adjustment on white space and position is still needed.

(P.S.: Yes, the 2nd section should read "tarw without ..." ... )

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand\arw[0]{%
  \begin{picture}(13,10)% allow some space after the tip
    \put(0,0.3em){\vector(1,0){10}}% shift it up a little
  \end{picture}}
  
\newcommand\tarw[0]{\tikz{\draw[-Latex] (0,0) -- (0.5,0);}}


\begin{document}
\section{arw}
Lorem \arw ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer rutrum Aenean vitae Phasellus risus. Vivamus et ridiculus Suspendisse Vestibulum hendrerit dolor ipsum congue.

Et ac quis pharetra convallis tempus pellentesque id Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada. Vitae et Maecenas Ut hendrerit quis \arw sagittis arcu mi vitae lobortis. At.

\arw

Tortor mus neque egestas habitant sed laoreet quis purus pede lacinia. Suscipit vel Vivamus laoreet dis Cras elit ipsum consequat eget orci. $a \arw b$ Massa $ab \mathrel{\arw} bc$ diam.

$a \arw b$

$ab \mathrel{\tarw bc}$\section{arw without any white space adjustments}
Lorem \tarw ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer rutrum Aenean vitae Phasellus risus. Vivamus et ridiculus Suspendisse Vestibulum hendrerit dolor ipsum congue.

Et ac quis pharetra convallis tempus pellentesque id Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada. Vitae et Maecenas Ut hendrerit quis \tarw sagittis arcu mi vitae lobortis. At.

\tarw

Tortor mus neque egestas habitant sed laoreet quis purus pede lacinia. Suscipit vel Vivamus laoreet dis Cras elit ipsum consequat eget orci. $a \tarw b$ Massa $ab \mathrel{\tarw} bc$ diam.

$a \tarw b$

$ab \mathrel{\tarw bc}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. It still sounds like the answer to my original question is (incredibly) no: there is no package with a symbol for such an arrow.